# AsyncFileUpload restrict file size to upload

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asyncfileupload

I am using AsyncFileUpload in order to allow users to asynchronously upload files.

I want to limit the size of the file to 1MB.

So far as to what I've seen I can only get the length of the file upon upload completion

like when upload starts:

(OnClientUploadStarted)

```
function UploadStarted(sender,args) 
{
   //if bigger than 1MB (approximately)
   if (args.get_length() > 1000000 ) 
   {
       ShowActionNotificationError( errorMessage); 
       return false;  
    }
}
```

args.get_length() is null , so I can't use it...

And when upload is completed:

(OnClientUploadComplete)

```
function UploadComplete(sender,args) 
{
    //if bigger than 1MB (approximately)
    if (args.get_length() > 1000000 ) 
    {
        ShowActionNotificationError( errorMessage); 
        return false;  
    }
}
```

works ok, but file was already uploaded...

So How can I know the size of the file before uploading it? am I missing something very simple?

I would really like to do it without handling HTTP Request length and the sort.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some substantial research I realize this cannot be done using AJAX.

As I look around at sites like yahoo mail and gmail, it's done by Flash.

in hotmail it's done with Silverlight.

there is a free (for now) flash upload control called Uploadify...

I am now working on integrating it.

if I'm wrong please correct me! :)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in the client side Upload Start event.

```
if (sender._inputFile.files[0].size >= maxFileSize) {
    sender._stopLoad();
}
```

_stopLoad will call your Upload Error event.

Answer (score 0):

You can check its size in `FileUploadComplete` method on server side

```
void FileUploadComplete(object objSender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.get_length() > 1000000 )
  {  
      ShowActionNotificationError( errorMessage);
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea but... what if a user chose a 100MB file to upload, and he waits a long time for it to complete, and only then he will realize it's too big? I want to know before...

Comment: This event handler is hit as soon as u select a file to upload...so u can check its size as soon as it enters this handler....if its with in limits, go ahead & upload else break out.

Comment: if it does get hit as soon as... how can I stop the proccess and show the user the error without refreshing?

Comment: I've checked it and it really seems like this event gets hit in the end, when the file is already fully uploaded...

Comment: I am aware that javascript can't access and know the filesize for security reasons. but... seeing working solutions like in gmail, makes me wonder how it was done...clearly it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes what Mithir told is correct. Its really cumbersome to give the modern user experience using HTML control.
Another alternative is [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the file size before the content is actually uploaded to the server, then your better off using asp component FileUpload. With this you can check and decide if you want to upload the file or not.

```
If FileUpload1.FileContent.Length <= DesiredFileSize Then

   <<Code to Upload the file>>

End If
```

Comment: The OP is looking for a client side check of the file size. This is a server side check. The file has to be uploaded anyway, which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

CERO Feb 14 '12 at 5:51

The FileUpload1 no is functional for UpdatePanel:

Controls that are not compatible with UpdatePanel controls

The following ASP.NET controls are not compatible with partial-page updates, and are therefore not designed to work inside an UpdatePanel control:

> Treeview control under several conditions. One is when callbacks are
>   enabled that are not part of an asynchronous postback. Another is when
>   you set styles directly as control properties instead of implicitly
>   styling the control by using a reference to CSS styles. Another is
>   when the EnableClientScript property is false (the default is true).
>   Another is if you change the value of the EnableClientScript property
>   between asynchronous postbacks.
>
> Menu control when you set styles directly as control properties
>   instead of implicitly styling the control by using a reference to CSS
>   styles.
>
> FileUpload and HtmlInputFile controls when they are used to upload
>   files as part of an asynchronous postback.
>
> GridView and DetailsView controls when their
>   EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks property is set to true. The default
>   is false.
>
> Login, PasswordRecovery, ChangePassword, and CreateUserWizard controls
>   whose contents have not been converted to editable templates.
>
> The Substitution control.

To use a FileUpload or HtmlInputFile control inside an UpdatePanel control, set the postback control that submits the file to be a PostBackTrigger control for the panel. The FileUpload and HtmlInputFile control can be used only in postback scenarios.